# How to create json pretty printer with conduit

Tags: haskell, stream, conduit

I'm learning `conduit` and want to create a processor that would take json input from stdin, process it in some way and then output to stdout. Pretty printing have been chosen just as example.

For now I want just decode json and print it. But seems like I have some problems with mismatched `Bytestring` types.

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource
   import Data.Aeson
   import Data.Conduit
   import qualified Data.Conduit.Combinators as CC
   import Data.Conduit (await, yield, (.|))
   import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BC
   import qualified Data.Conduit.Binary as CB
   import Data.JsonStream.Parser hiding ((.|))
   import qualified Data.Text as T
   import System.IO (stdin, stdout)


   jsonParse :: Conduit BC.ByteString IO (T.Text, Value)
   jsonParse = doParse parseOutput
     where
       parseOutput :: ParseOutput (T.Text, Value)
       parseOutput = runParser (objectItems value)

       doParse :: ParseOutput (T.Text, Value) -> Conduit BC.ByteString IO (T.Text, Value)
       doParse out = case out of
           ParseYield value newOutput -> do
               yield value
               doParse newOutput
           ParseNeedData cont ->
               awaitForever $ \i -> doParse (cont i)
           ParseDone remaining -> return ()
           ParseFailed err -> error err

   main = runConduit $ CB.sourceHandle stdin .| jsonParse .| CC.map (encode . snd) .| CB.sinkHandle stdout


   /tmp/some1/app/Main.hs:25:13: error:
       • Couldn't match type ‘Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString’
                        with ‘ByteString’
         NB: ‘ByteString’ is defined in ‘Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal’
             ‘Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString’
               is defined in ‘Data.ByteString.Internal’
         Expected type: Conduit ByteString IO (T.Text, Value)
           Actual type: ConduitM
                          Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString (T.Text, Value) IO ()
       • In the expression: awaitForever $ \ i -> doParse (cont i)
         In a case alternative:
             ParseNeedData cont -> awaitForever $ \ i -> doParse (cont i)
         In the expression:
           case out of
             ParseYield value newOutput
               -> do yield value
                     doParse newOutput
             ParseNeedData cont -> awaitForever $ \ i -> doParse (cont i)
             ParseDone remaining -> return ()
             ParseFailed err -> error err
      |
   25 | awaitForever $ \i -> doParse (cont i)
      | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

   /tmp/some1/app/Main.hs:25:34: error:
       • Couldn't match type ‘ByteString’
                        with ‘Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString’
         NB: ‘Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString’
               is defined in ‘Data.ByteString.Internal’
             ‘ByteString’ is defined in ‘Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal’
         Expected type: ConduitM
                          Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString (T.Text, Value) IO ()
           Actual type: Conduit ByteString IO (T.Text, Value)
       • In the expression: doParse (cont i)
         In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘\ i -> doParse (cont i)’
         In the expression: awaitForever $ \ i -> doParse (cont i)
      |
   25 | awaitForever $ \i -> doParse (cont i)
      | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

   /tmp/some1/app/Main.hs:29:46: error:
       • Couldn't match type ‘ByteString’
                        with ‘Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString’
         NB: ‘Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString’
               is defined in ‘Data.ByteString.Internal’
             ‘ByteString’ is defined in ‘Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal’
         Expected type: ConduitM
                          Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString Data.Void.Void IO ()
           Actual type: ConduitM ByteString Data.Void.Void IO ()
       • In the second argument of ‘(.|)’, namely
           ‘jsonParse .| CC.map (encode . snd) .| CB.sinkHandle stdout’
         In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
           ‘CB.sourceHandle stdin
              .| jsonParse .| CC.map (encode . snd) .| CB.sinkHandle stdout’
         In the expression:
           runConduit
             $ CB.sourceHandle stdin
                 .| jsonParse .| CC.map (encode . snd) .| CB.sinkHandle stdout
      |
   29 | main = runConduit $ CB.sourceHandle stdin .| jsonParse .| CC.map (encode . snd) .| CB.sinkHandle stdout
      | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

   /tmp/some1/app/Main.hs:29:84: error:
       • Couldn't match type ‘Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString’
                        with ‘ByteString’
         NB: ‘ByteString’ is defined in ‘Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal’
             ‘Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString’
               is defined in ‘Data.ByteString.Internal’
         Expected type: ConduitM ByteString Data.Void.Void IO ()
           Actual type: ConduitM
                          Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString Data.Void.Void IO ()
       • In the second argument of ‘(.|)’, namely ‘CB.sinkHandle stdout’
         In the second argument of ‘(.|)’, namely
           ‘CC.map (encode . snd) .| CB.sinkHandle stdout’
         In the second argument of ‘(.|)’, namely
           ‘jsonParse .| CC.map (encode . snd) .| CB.sinkHandle stdout’
      |
   29 | main = runConduit $ CB.sourceHandle stdin .| jsonParse .| CC.map (encode . snd) .| CB.sinkHandle stdout
      | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bytestring` defines both a strict type (in `Data.ByteString`) & a lazy type (in the module `Data.ByteString.Lazy`).  Fixing your code might by as easy as importing `Data.ByteString.Char8` instead of the lazy one.  If the libraries use a mixture, you can convert with [toStrict](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.2/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html#v:toStrict) and [fromStrict](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.2/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html#v:fromStrict)